# integration test in .Net for rest api between two microservices

Tags: .net, rest, asp.net-web-api2, integration-testing, microservices

What is the proper way to perform an integration test between two microservices that communicate between them self in REST API?

Say I want to post data from one microservice to another, how can I mock the sending from one point and receiving it on the other end, and be able to validate that the data is correct.

What is the right way of doing that, in .Net if possible?

Comment: "mock"? Integration testing should not include mocked components (different from unit testing) if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you right?

But as you describe I think you can just Add Reference to your controller and call the method that you want to test.

Best Regards